# setInterval change speed under action

Tags: javascript, performance, time, settimeout, setinterval

I don't know how I can change speed while function in setInterval works..

In code:

```
var timeout, count = 0, speed = 5000;

                  $('#stage').mousedown(function() {
                    timeout = setInterval(function() {
                        speed = parseInt(speed / 1.3); // HERE I want change speed
                        create(speed); // Some Function
                    }, speed); // This speed, I don't know how to change
                });

                $('#stage').mouseup(function() {
                    count = 0;
                    clearInterval(timeout);
                });
```

This work but speed is outside function is const (5000)

Thanks a lot for all helps!

Comment: Use a `setTimeout` loop instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setInterval(funtion(),time) change time on runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576106/setintervalfuntion-time-change-time-on-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a named function in order to pass it into a new setTimeout function.

```
var speed = 5000;
var timer;

$('#stage').mousedown(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(handleTick, speed);
});

$('#stage').mouseup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);    
});

var handleTick = function () {
    speed = parseInt(speed / 1.3);
    timer = setTimeout(handleTick, speed);
};
```

Comment: That will never stop! When you call setTimeout in handleTick function, you need to set timer again, otherwise clearTimeout will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't change the delay after a call to `setInterval`. However, you could call `setTimeout` in a recursive manner :

```
var speed = 5000;

function doSomething() {
    console.log(speed); // prints from 5000 to 1000
    speed -= 1000;
};

setTimeout(function () {
    doSomething(); // changes the global "speed" var internally
    speed && setTimeout(arguments.callee, speed);
}, speed);
```

Comment: `arguments.callee` is deprecated. Better use named functions instead.