# Change interval in Setinterval

Tags: javascript

I'm new to jQuery, I wanted to change the interval in Setinterval every time it gets executed. But in my code it's executed every 1 sec and not incrementing at all

Here's my code,

```
 <script>
     var time=1000;
        function myFunction() {

         setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, time);
         time=time+4000;
    }
  </script>
```

I think I'm getting this concept wrong, any help with brief explanation where I'm doing wrong will be helpful

Comment: [Duplicate Already Asked Here][1] how to change interval time at runtime


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576106/setintervalfunction-time-change-time-on-runtime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the interval of SetInterval while it's running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280263/changing-the-interval-of-setinterval-while-its-running)

Answer (score 3):

setInterval is called till its stopped.

What you should use if you want variable timer is setTimeout.

```
 <script>
     var time=1000;
        function myFunction() {

         setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); myFunction() }, time);
         time=time+4000; // seconds
    }
  </script>
```